# No module named 'airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor'

Tags: python, airflow

I tried to run a dag in airflow where one task involves a file sensor.

When I try to run it:

```python
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator



dag = DAG('file_sensor_dag',
          start_date=datetime(2017, 3, 20), catchup=False)
          
          
          
dummy_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', retries=3, dag=dag)

sensor_task = FileSensor(task_id= "file_sensor_task", poke_interval= 30,  filepath= "\root\cr1.csv", dag=dag)

dummy_operator >> sensor_task
```

It throws the following error

```
No module named 'airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor'
```

Comment: could you please expand on the code and the error traceback? And perhaps give a bit more context on the environment you're trying to run it.

Comment: what is your airflow version ? Check and compare that with the source code for file_sensor.

Comment: airflow version v1.9.0

Answer (score 0):

For everyone met this scenario, we should use ***airflow.sensors.filesystem import FileSensor*** instead of *from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor*